# Unable to "click()" on an element in Selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, click, webdriver

I have recorded an automatic test with Selenium, exported it into JAVA code and now I am fighting to complete it. The problem is that I cannot get `click();` done.

This is my code, a part of it:

```
try {
  assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nowa oferta dokument']"))
          .getText().matches("^Nowa oferta dokument$"));
} catch (Error e) {
  verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nowa oferta dokument']")).click();
```

First I find the element using xpath and then using xpath I want to click on it so its settings open.

I have tried many ways to solve it, and still can't figure it out. Do you see any solution for this one?

HTML:

```html
<a href="offer_view.html?id=1007" class="linkOffer firepath-matching-node"></a>
<p class="photo"><img src="img/document.png"></p>
                
<p class="name">Nowa oferta dokument</p>
                
<p class="price">123 zł</p>
                
<div class="rate ctrlViewRateOffer" data-value="0.0000">
                  
<span class="stars"></span>
                  
<span class="stars"></span>
                  
<span class="stars"></span>
                  
<span class="stars"></span>
                  
<span class="stars"></span>
                
</div>
                
<p class="date"></p>
                
<div class="hide info">
                                      
<p><a href="#" class="ctrlClickSubmit edit" title="Edytuj" data-value="u_document_1007" data-form="formAddOffer"></a></p>
                    
<p><a class="ctrlClickSubmit delete" title="Usuń" data-value="delete_1007" data-form="formManageOffer" href="#"></a></p>
                    
<p><a href="offer_manage.html?id=1007" class="buttons optionsEventsBtn nohover" title="Zarządzaj ofertą"></a></p>
                                    
<p class="type">e-book</p>
                  
<p>To jest opis nowo tworzonej oferty - dokumentu, który wystawię na sprzedaż, a następnie u...</p>
                
</div>
                
<div class="bgInfo"></div>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML representation of an element? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information instead of adding it to the comments, it is much more readable there.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is that

By.xpath("//*[text()='Nowa oferta dokument']")

is matching more than one element... 
Also, check if the returned element/s is clickable

Comment: There's only one element with that name on the page. I'm not sure how to check it's clickable.Do you know any other methods familiar to click that work the same?

Comment: Ok. The html as you showed did not tell us if there are other layers blocking the click... One way to check if the element is clickable is by using explicit wait conditions: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourDriver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nowa oferta dokument']")));`

Comment: I've tried the code you gave me, and I set the driver to wait 10 seconds for the element to be clickable. It found the element and highlighted it but it did not open the page. I added "click()" at the end of it and I added new command: " driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Nowa oferta dokument']")).click(); " and none of these worked. :( Do you know how to overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your selector is wrong for one:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='name'][text()='Nowa oferta dokument']")).click();
```

Should hopefully work. If not, your element is probably not clickable due to other elements in front of it.

In which case, you can simulate the click using javascript:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='name'][text()='Nowa oferta dokument']")));
```

Your CURRENT selector IS matching multiple elements.  Since the element you are trying to select is at least two elements in, it is matching every parent object in the tree above the element you actually want, since they ALL contain that as the text().

Comment: Haven't downvoted, but I suppose this is at least because of the `@name` attribute check - but is there no `name` attribute being set to  `Nowa oferta dokument` on any element..

Comment: I must have read the source code in his comment wrong.  Comments don't format code worth a crap.   It is fixed now.